# Simple WIX Installer just coping file doesn't work, what is going wrong?

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3

Here is my code just to copy a file however I don't see any directory created in program files or any notepad.exe file being copied? Where I am going wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="8806367C-FFA1-40C7-B16A-462CF6D941BE" 
            Name="Test_Product_Name" Version="0.0.1" Manufacturer="Test_Company_Name" Language="1033">
      <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Comments="Windows Installer Package"/>
      <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>

      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
         <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="20211022_test">
               <Component Id="ApplicationFiles" Guid="172743A1-08E5-483C-96F1-0CE1373F2AF1">
                  <File Id="ApplicationFile1" Source="notepad.exe"/>
               </Component>
            </Directory>
         </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
         <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationFiles"/>
      </Feature>
   </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Did you look in the ProgramFiles (x86) folder?

Comment: Yes, I sorted it. Thanks. It was indeed in ProgramFiles (x86)

Answer (score 0):

Your source shows a 32bit MSI so Program Files (x86) is where it'll go.